# np.core.records.fromarrays doesn't work in program but works in console

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, record

I am currently running the following Python script (test.py)

```
import numpy as np
x = ['Time', 'FX_1', 'FY_1', 'FZ_1', \
    'AX_1', 'AY_1', 'FX_2', 'FY_2', 'FZ_2', 'AX_2', 'AY_2']
np.core.records.fromarrays(np.array([np.array([]) for i in xrange(len(x))]), names=x)
```

which should give me the following output

```
>>> rec.array([],
      dtype=[('Time', '<f8'), ('FX_1', '<f8'), ('FY_1', '<f8'), ('FZ_1', '<f8'), \
             ('AX_1', '<f8'), ('AY_1', '<f8'), ('FX_2', '<f8'), ('FY_2', '<f8'), \
             ('FZ_2', '<f8'), ('AX_2', '<f8'), ('AY_2', '<f8')])
```

Unfortunately, it **doesn't work** when I run it **through a .py** file but **it does work** when I run it line by line **through in-console** Python. When I run the script, I get

```
python test.py
>>> []
```

Note: This **was working** in both instances before I made a virtual environment through Conda for the 32-bit version and (Numpy / SciPy through an unofficial wheel version https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). The version I am using are

- NumPy -- 1.13.3+mkl
- SciPy -- 1.0.0

I am running 32 bit, and both NumPy versions (printed) are 1.13.3. The 64 bit version is also encountering the same issue (1.11.3).

Sorry if this seems like an easy question, but I haven't been able to find a solution since the virtual environment. It just seems weird that the in-line console can run it fine, but can't when I run the code through a script. It's important for me to keep this structure in the creation process. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did your `python` version change when you updated?  String parsing was modified heavily between `python` 2 and 3.  Other possibility is it's just a display difference between versions.  Try `print(np.core . . . .))` or `np.core . . .).dtype`

Comment: Ah I realized my really obvious mistake. It looks like both outputs are correct.

Printing out the result gives you what looks like an empty list, but in reality, is actually just NumPy shortening the full-result because the array doesn't contain any values (all empty arrays). When you add a .dtype to the result, you'll see exactly the details of that "list-like" output. Putting in values, then causes the output to be exactly as I want.

That shorthand display really threw me for a loop.